# Session State in WebAPI .NET Core

Tags: session, asp.net-core-webapi

I have read over and over again that Session state is a bad idea for REST Api's.

For some time we have had a number of applications that use a Session to store very large responses from web services per user.

All this is stored in a Session and accessed using the session id and it seems to be ok but I am sure it can be better.

Now we are redesigning the API and I want to try and avoid the state if possible and make it stateless.

**Questions**

1) I am aware of databases etc, is there any other way to manage per user data where the data is coming from 3rd party services?

2) Continue as normal as in if it works carry on using it?

3) Would managing state in DB vs Session be faster (have not done/seen any performance tests)

Keep in mind the idea is to minimize the calls to the 3rd party on per user basis. As each call costs financially.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Use cache instead. Just inject `IDistributedCache`, and incorporate part of the user (id, etc.) in the key you set with that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I though about that and using key for cache, but I am wondering if cache might cause any issues when clearing per user data, or storing per user data.

Comment: Not if you segregate by user.

Comment: You think performance wise this would be better than Session? As for us performance is the key, also doing it that way I guess i would use something like a GUID as I would no longer have session id, also what do you mean by segregate?